# Updating page number on API call with recursion

Tags: recursion, elixir, agent

I'm making API calls and the service I am using only returns a certain number of results per page(I need all the results, not just first page). Fortunately they have a key on the JSON object called "total_pages" that says how many pages there are. There's also a "current_page" attribute. You can add a pager to the end of the URL you are calling like so: "example.com/endpoint&page=2"

I realized that the only way to get all of the pages is to loop through the total_pages number and somehow create another call to the api with the new pager info.

This can be done with a for or while loop by incrementing the current_page attribute but I can't seem to figure out how to do it with recursion. I have come up with a way to do it with Agent that holds and updates the current_page state but it seems unnecessary.

```
Agent.start(fn -> 1 end, name: current_page)
Agent.update(:current_page, fn curr_page -> state + 1 end)
```

Is there a way to do this in Elixir, maybe with a cond statement that checks if the current_page == total_pages and if not it runs a function that calls the API again?

THanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, an Agent is overkill for this. A simple recursive function can solve this elegantly. Here's a basic implementation that should help you get started:

```
defmodule A do
  def fetch(current_page) do
    response = get("/?page=#{current_page}")
    if response.total_pages == current_page do
      :ok
    else
      fetch(current_page + 1)
    end
  end

  # Sample function that acts like an HTTP GET request.
  def get(url) do
    IO.puts "GET #{url}"
    %{total_pages: 5}
  end
end

A.fetch(1)
```

Output:

```
GET /?page=1
GET /?page=2
GET /?page=3
GET /?page=4
GET /?page=5
```

We start with page 1. After fetching the contents of the page, we check if the current page equals the `total_pages` in the response. If it does, we stop, otherwise we recurse with `current_page` set to `current_page + 1`.

Comment: btw what would be the FP way/ what do you recommend for collecting all the info that comes back from the request each time around? Should I just create a new list that gets the data from the new page added on to it, with something like ++ for joining lists? (The ultimate goal is to compile all the information that comes back from every page) Pls let me know if this should be it's own question. Thanks

Comment: You can keep track of that by adding a second argument to `fetch`. Initially, call it with `[]`. Then every time you call `fetch` for the next page, add the data you want to collect to the list, e.g. `fetch(current_page + 1, [new_data | old_data])`. Then, instead of `:ok`, return `old_data`, which'll make the function return only the data at the end of the recursion. Let me know if that clears it up!